# Find closure to a space of essentially supported $L^2$ functions

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis, measure-theory, partial-differential-equations

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^N$, be an open and bounded domain and let:

$$L^2_* = \{ q \in L^2(\Omega)\, |\, \text{Vol(ess sup(}q)) \in [0, 0.9*\text{Vol(}\Omega\text{)}] \}$$

I want to understand whether $L^2_*$ is complete.

Any closed subspace of $L^2(\Omega)$ (which is complete) is complete. I tried many directions in showing that $L^2_*$ is closed, mostly in terms of a converging $\text{Vol(ess supp(}q))$ but none of them worked.

My bet at the moment is that the closure of $L^2_*$ is:

$$\bar {L^2_*} = \{ q \in L^2(\Omega)\, |\, \text{Vol(ess sup(}q)) \in [0, 0.9*\text{Vol(}\Omega\text{)}] \},$$

(taking a closure of a closed interval over here),

and so $\bar L^2_* = L^2_*$, thus, $L^2_*$ is a closed subspace of $L^2$ and therefore complete. Is this wrong? Can you suggest another direction perhaps?

Comment: What are you assuming about $\Omega$? Are you assuming that is open?

Comment: Yes, open and bounded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that there is a sequence $(f_n)\subset L^2_\ast$ which converges in $L^2$ to $f\notin L^2_*$. Then, the volume of the essential support of $f$ is equal to, say, $0.9|\Omega| + \epsilon$. From this you can infer that there exists $\delta>0$ such that $|f|\geq \delta$ on a set of measure $0.9|\Omega| + \epsilon/2$. Now, since $\Omega$ has finite volume, $L^2$ convergence implies $L^1$ convergence and every sequence converging in $L^1$ has a subsequence converging almost uniformly. Hence, we can extract a subsequence $(f_{n_k})$ converging almost uniformly to $f$, but this means that $|f_{n_k}|>\delta/2$ on a set of measure $0.9|\Omega| + \epsilon/4$ for $k$ sufficiently large, which is a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks @ajr, that was very helpful!